# Python DataFrames Create 'Create/False' Column from 3 other 'True/False' Columns

Tags: python, finance, data-science

I'm working this with financial DataFrame. I want to create a df['LB4'] column, that returns true if all of LB1, LB2, and LB3 are true.

```
Date        Open    High    Low     Close    Volume     LB1     LB2     LB3                             
2005-01-03  4.63    4.65    4.47    4.52    173354034   False   False   False
2005-01-04  4.56    4.68    4.50    4.57    274515332   False   False   False
2005-01-05  4.60    4.66    4.58    4.61    170210264   False   False   True
2005-01-06  4.62    4.64    4.52    4.61    176469496   False   True    True
2005-01-07  4.64    4.97    4.62    4.95    558932752   True    True    False
```

Any ideas?

I am new to Python and would appreciate any help.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Starting with this (modified your example a bit):

```
In [1095]: df
Out[1095]: 
     LB1    LB2    LB3
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False   True
3   True   True   True
4   True   True   True
```

---

You can use bitwise `&`:

```
In [1096]: df.LB1 & df.LB2 & df.LB3
Out[1096]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

---

Alternatively, with `df.all`:

```
In [1097]: df[['LB%d' %i for i in range(1, 4)]].all(axis=1)
Out[1097]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

You can shorten the list comprehension to `df.select_dtypes([bool]).all(axis=1)` if you know only those columns are boolean and nothing else.